# Prove the continuity of the map defined on locally compact Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces

A ternary Banach space $(A,[,])$ is complete normed space with a linear ternary map $[,]:A\times A\times A \to A$ satisfying $\vert \vert[a,b,c] \vert \vert \leq \vert \vert a \vert \vert \vert \vert b \vert \vert \vert \vert c \vert \vert$. Let $X$ be locally compact Hausdorff space and $f_i:X \to A$ be continuous functions for $1\leq i \leq 3$. Consider $f:X \to A$ defined as $$f(x)= [f_1(x),f_2(x),f_3(x)]$$

> Is the function $f$ continuous?

Let $U$ be open ball in $A$. I can see that if $U$ is open ball centred at $0$ then $f^{-1}(U)$ is also open but I'm unable to see it in general.

Comment: You’d be done if the ternary map were continuous. Can you show that fact first?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Isnt it obvious using sequential criteria as we are dealing with normed spaces?

Comment: Yes, if the ternary map were linear that would work, but is it? You don’t say.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  Yes, they are linear. Sorry , I don't see how continuity of ternary map helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary map $[,]: A^3 \to A$ is continuous: it is linear and bounded on the Banach space $A^3$, e.g.,  or if $(x_n,y_n,z_n) \to (x,y,z)$ in $A^3$ then $x_n \to x, y_n \to y, z_n \to z$ in $A$ and so
$$\| [x_n,y_n,z_n] - [x,y,z]\| = \| [x_n-x,y_n-y,z_n-z)]\| \le \|x_n-x\| \|y_n-y\| \|z_n-z\| \to 0$$ as $n \to \infty$ etc.

Knowing that, then given $f_1,f_2,f_3: X \to A$ continuous, the map $F: X \to A^3, F(x)= (f_1(x), f_2(x), f_3(x))$ is continuous too, as $\pi_i \circ F = f_i$ for $i=1,2,3$ and a map into a product is continuous iff the compositions with the projections all are (universal property of the product topology). The map $f$ you’re interested in is just $[,] \circ F$ and so continuous as the composition of continuous maps. QED.

Comment: Note that the topology on $X$ is irrelevant only the continuity is used.

Comment: Does the same results holds if we replace linearity by component wise linearity?

Comment: @MathLover if that means my proof still works, yes, of course. Would it?

Comment: I don't see it because you're using linearity.

Comment: @MathLover so you want to only assume that $[x-y,u,v] = [x,u,v] -[y,u,v]$ e.g. That might not be enough. It’s hard to come up with counterexamples though.

Comment: Yes, i want to assume that in all three components.

Answer (score 1):

$f= [\cdot, \cdot, \cdot] \circ (f_1, f_2, f_3)$ is continuous as a composition of continuous functions. Of course, it must be shown that $[\cdot, \cdot, \cdot]$ is continuous, but this is routine.

Comment: Does the same results holds if we replace linearity by component wise linearity?

Comment: Yes, it does. You can try to do something Cauchy-Schwarz like probably.

Comment: Do you mind writing starting few steps?